# web.py - specify address and port

Tags: python, web.py

How to specify listening address and port in [web.py](http://webpy.org/)? Something like:

```
web.application( urls, host="33.44.55.66", port=8080 )
```

**Edit**

I would like to avoid using the default web.py command line parsing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From API docmentation of [web.py](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.httpserver):

```
 module web.httpserver
    function runsimple(func,server_address=('0.0.0.0', 8080))
```

Runs CherryPy WSGI server hosting WSGI app func. The directory static/ is hosted statically.

**Example code**

```
import web

class MyApplication(web.application):
    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('0.0.0.0', port))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApplication(urls, globals())
    app.run(port=8888)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you're using web.py's built-in webserver, you can just append the port to the command:

```
python app.py 8080
```

I haven't tried ever with the listening address, but perhaps it will accept 1.2.3.4:8080 as the format.

Comment: Good intuition, it accepts address too. Although, I would like to use my own command line parsing and do not mix it with default web.py command line parser

Comment: Do you mean to run it from a 'normal' webserver like Apache or something? If that's the case, you'll need to play around with the Apache config to determine which address/port combo should point to your script.

Answer (score 7):

```
URLS = ("/", index)

class index:
    def GET:
        ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = web.application(URLS, globals())
     web.httpserver.runsimple(app.wsgifunc(), ("0.0.0.0", 8888))
```

Answer (score 5):

you can see the follow code in wsgi.py:

```
server_addr = validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, ''))
if os.environ.has_key('PORT'): # e.g. Heroku
    server_addr = ('0.0.0.0', intget(os.environ['PORT']))

return httpserver.runsimple(func, server_addr)
```

so, you can set the web server port by add environ variable:

```
import os
os.environ["PORT"] = "80"
```