# How to run web.py in public ip

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

How to run a webpy code in public IP. If i give LAN IP it works fine but when i try to do the same with public IP I'm not able to do the same, it is giving as "socket.error: No socket could be created". 
I've tried as shown below:

```
python code.py <IP Address>:8080
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web.py - specify address and port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444913/web-py-specify-address-and-port)

Comment: specifying <ip>:<port> should would fine... "No socket could be created" is what you'll get if your computer doesn't support that IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to give the port number in router. It works fine when I assigned to router. Thanks.