# Problem with local server, starting react app

Tags: reactjs, server, local

When I am trying to 'npm start' react app https://github.com/0wczar/airframe-react and then go to local server at http://0.0.0.0:4100/ I got ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID. What should I do to repair my local server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web.py "Hello world" not working - ERR\_ADDRESS\_INVALID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926218/web-py-hello-world-not-working-err-address-invalid)

Comment: @JuChengJiang The question is about IP addresses. It isn't specific to React or Python.

Comment: Yes. you are right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entered the wrong server URL. It should be localhost or 127.0.0.1, I think.

```
http://localhost:4100
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:4100
```

Comment: Thanks! http://localhost:4100 works. But why it's that URL? When vs code tells me that it should be http://0.0.0.0:4100/?

Comment: @modsell `0.0.0.0` is not a valid address. See the link below your question for an explanation.

Comment: It may help you to understand the difference. https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1